# Trigger to replace inserted value

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I need to make a replacment of values in table that have just been inserted.
In this case I have table 'table1' with column 'result'.

If I perform this command:

```
INSERT INTO 'table1'('result','some_field') VALUES ('1','some_data')
```

I want to see this data inserted into the table:

```
|'result' |'some_field'|
----------------------- 
|'success'|'some_data' |
```

Is it possible to make this with triggers, or I should do replacement via code when I'm creating the query?

Comment: I don't understand what the purpose is of having the result be '1' when immediately afterward you want the result to be 'success'.  Is there some intermediate step or action that you are not including?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you want to have the data correct only in your query.  Would this work?

```
select case when result = '1' then 'Success' 
            else result 
       end case, 
       some_field
from table
```

Comment: Basically it is good solution.
Only problem here, is when I have a lots of indexes definitions.
Query would be enormous